Different results for function() and fn(). PHP
I have a problem.
$this->allIds->each(function ($id) {
    $this->checked[$id] = $this->checkedAll;
});

And this:
$this->allIds->each(fn($id) => $this->checked[$id] = $this->checkedAll);

return different results... Why? :)
In full version i have this:
Result with function()
In short version i have this:
Result with fn()
Thanks :)

Topically related: Laravel each() method

When using each() to iterate over a Laravel collection,
returning false stops the iteration:

If you would like to stop iterating through the items, you may return false from your closure

In your case, $this->checkedAll is false, so the closure returns false and you get only one element in your $this->checked array.


Arrow function syntax implement an implicit return.  This differs from traditional closures which require an explicit return inside the curly braced body.

In your working traditional closure, there is no return statement, so a null return is implied.  Relevant reading: What's the difference between return; and no return?

Laravel's collection method each() does not work identically to PHP's native function array_walk() for arrays. each() does traverse the entire payload, but also has a feature to conditionally halt iteration as soon as false is returned. array_walk() is not built this way; there is no in-built short-circuiting functionality.
Furthermore, Laravel does not currently have a collection method that closer resembles array_walk() (there is no walk() collection method).
This means you will either need to prevent a false return inside of each()'s closure or choose a different iteration technique.


Some workarounds: Demo

Revert to long closure syntax (still professional looking):
$this->allIds->each(function ($id) {
    $this->checked[$id] = $this->checkedAll;
});


Convert falsey return values to null to prevent short-circuiting (looks ugly/hacky/unexpected):
$this->allIds->each(
    fn($id) => ($this->checked[$id] = $this->checkedAll) ?: null
);


Use a classic loop (reasonably professional):
foreach ($this->allIds as $id) {
    $this->checked[$id] = $this->checkedAll;
}


Convert the collection to an array and use array_walk() -- implied return value is ignored (not the most direct way):
array_walk(
    $this->allIds->toArray(),
    fn($id) => $this->checked[$id] = $this->checkedAll
);



